# Error R10 - Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, heroku

I'm building a Telegram bot in Python which fetches stars of Github repos of an organisation on command and displays them.

The bot runs and shows the welcome message but doesn't respond to any command and then crashes giving the error,

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 2018-11-17T17:13:40.232216+00:00
>
> heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
>
> 2018-11-17T17:13:40.309943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 137
>
> 2018-11-17T17:13:40.370462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2018-11-17T17:13:41.899621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gcijbossbot.herokuapp.com request_id=4cf3c8f0-940b-4c73-aee7-842b1949e395 fwd="115.97.36.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-11-17T17:13:44.029680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=gcijbossbot.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=94937fe2-56d2-4f4c-bad9-1fe679442db4 fwd="115.97.36.250"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I tried switching the Procfile from

```
web: python Stars.py
```

to

```
worker: python Stars.py
```

but then the app doesn't work at all.

Stars.py code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import requests

def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('Ahoy {}! Welcome to JBossStarsBot. \n\nTo get started, use the /stars command to fetch the stars from the GitHub repos of JBoss'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))


def stars(bot, update):
    api = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/JBossOutreach/repos')
    json = api.json()
    stars = ''
    for i in range(len(json)):
        stars = stars + '\n' + res[i]['name'] + ' : ' + str(res[i]['stargazers_count'])

    update.message.reply_text('Here\'s the list of all the JBoss repositories on GitHub along with their respective star count. \n\n' + stars + '\n\nTo get the stars of a specific repository, enter the name of the repository.')


def repo_stars(bot, update):
    api = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/JBossOutreach')
    json = api.json()
    star = ''
    for i in range(len(json)):
        cur = res[i]['name']
        if cur == update.message.text:
            star = star + cur + ' : ' + str(res[i]['stargazers_count'])
        if cur == '':
            star = 'No such repository found.'

    bot.send_message(update.message.chat_id, star)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('stars', stars))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, repo_stars))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't used Django, or Flask. Simply python-telegram-bot and requests.

Comment: Does your app provide a web service? Does it listen for HTTP requests and respond with HTTP responses? That's what Heroku is for. If your code doesn't do that it's not a good fit.

Comment: Yes. It's a telegram bot.

Comment: Okay, so what's in `Stars.py`? How do you set up your server to listen? We can't help with code we can't see.

Comment: Here's the code: https://github.com/arihantbansal/JBossTelegramStarsBot

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained. We're not going to go off-site and dig through your repository to find the problem. Please post the relevant parts _here_ as a [mcve].

Comment: Added the code to the question description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Telegram, but it looks like you aren't actually running an HTTP server. Instead, your code is [periodically polling for updates](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html):

> The updater can be started as a polling service or, for production, use a webhook to receive updates.

On Heroku you need to run an actual HTTP server, binding to the port provided by the `PORT` environment variable. It looks like [`start_webhook`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.start_webhook) can do this, e.g. with something like

```
import os

def main():
    # ...
    port = os.getenv('PORT', default=8000)
    updater.start_webhook(port=port)
```